# Where is my drawable folder?

Tags: android, directory, drawable, dpi

When I go into the res folder for my project I only see the drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, and drawable-mdpi folders. Every tutorial I've read says put the image in the drawable folder. Am I supposed to have one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't get created automatically when you create the project like the others.  Just create a folder named `drawable` in the same location as those other folders.  You also do this for `anim`, `animator`, `values-x`, `raw`, `menu`, and basically any other specialty resource folder that you may need.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a PNG image file you should place it into drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi or drawable-hdpi, depending on its resolutions. Ideally you should provide three versions (or four, with xhdpi) of your bitmap for the different screen pixel densities.

If you have a drawable resource defined in XML that is independent of pixel dentity (e.g. a [Shape Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)) you should place it in drawable.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the project tab on the left
2. Under android Right click on the `drawable` (under folder "`res`").
3. Select Show in explorer or Reveal in finder

You should be able to see the `drawable` folder